# django: save_model multiple models

Tags: python, django, modeladmin

i have set a property as
list_editable in django... Then I edit this property at couple items and click save. Everything is fine BUT I want to know what function is BEFORE the save_model().

I want to do something like this (tho I cant find a function like save_models()) in ModelAdmin class

```
def save_models(queryset):
    print "Here comes something I need to do"
    for model in queryset:
        model.save()
    print "Another thing I need to do comes here"
```

So is there a function like "save_models()" that is triggered when click saved and saving multiple objects? I really need to overwrite it.

Comment: you can translate code to model itself with pre and post save signals or overwriting save method. This approach can be a solution for you?

Comment: well no - if I understand you correctly. I cant have my "prints" before and after everything else in save_model(). Cause I want to trigger the 1st before any model is saved, then save all models (saving multiple instances not just one) and then trigger the 2nd.